# Using live method with Hover event

Tags: jquery

How can i use live method with hover event? it's possible to do? or i'll need to use live method on mouseover and mouseout events.

Answer (score 1):

[`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is a shortcut to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Just bind it with...

```
$('a')
 .live('mouseenter', function() { ... })
 .live('mouseleave', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's hover is a shortcut/shim for ies mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Bind simply using the live like Any other event.

```
$('selector')
.live('mouseenter',fun..)
.live('mouseleave',fun....);
```

But their will be a performance overhead, so it typically isn't encouraged.  You should really use delegate for a speed increase.